# How to define the properties of a useState object having extended type and returned by a function, while maintaining readability?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am experiencing with using TypeScript in React states. My intention is to use objects with strict types instead of several separate `useState` statements, and with desirably no additional classes to represent these object structures (only interfaces). I have the following scenario:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<IStateType>(..code1..);
```

In the above line `IStateType` extends another interface, let us call that `IStateSubType`:

```
export interface IStateType extends IStateSubType {...}
```

Since objects with `IStateSubType` are instantiated more than once in my project, I would create a function to initialise these objects in order to reduce code redundancy:

```
function getEmptyStateSubType(): IStateSubType(..code2..);
```

In this function *code2* part would define the properties required by `IStateSubType` and return the resulting object. I would call `getEmptyStateSubType()` in *code1* part, then I would extend its returning objects' properties with missing ones required by `IStateType` as below:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<IStateType>(
  (): IStateType => {
    const tmpValue: IStateSubType = getEmptyStateSubType();
    const value: IStateType = {
      ...tmpValue,
      foo: bar
    };
    return value;
  }
);
```

Using the above implementation I did achieve my goal to strictly use types in both the state and the function and there are also no redundant lines, but at the end of the day not only did the number of lines increased in my code, but I also feel that readability decreased greatly while unnecessary complexity increased. I was wondering if there are better solutions to achieve my goals: maintain readability and enforce type usage. How to implement this with shorter and more readable code?

Comment: can you share the whole code?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do well with squishy words like "better" and "Thoughts?". See the [help/dont-ask]. Perhaps it would be better to simply ask how to do this in fewer lines or less verbosely.

Comment: I guess there's also [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Looks too much like _example code_ to be ready for review, I think @ÁdámBozzay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```js
const [state, setState] = useState<IStateType>(
    () => ({...getEmptyStateSubType(), foo: 'bar' })
);
```

But nothing stops you from creating a `getStateType` function

```js
const getStateType =
    (o: Omit<IStateType, keyof IStateSubType>): IStateType =>
        (({...getEmptyStateSubType(), ...o}))

const [state, setState] = useState<IStateType>(getStateType({ foo: 'bar' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Though my question was quite vague, for anyone facing similar issues in the future allow me to share my second attempt for implementing this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<IStateType>(
  () => { // I removed the type, since it is already enforced by useState
    const value: IStateType = {
      ...getEmptyStateSubType(), // I used spread on method return value
      foo: bar
    };
    return value;
  }
);
```